# While building project "Build container dead"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

While I am building a project with code build AWS Error is coming which says "Build container is dead". I am not able to find the reason for it.

Comment: If you create a thread in the [AWS CodeBuild forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=230) we'd be happy to help investigate this for you.

Comment: Without more information we cant tell the reason. Please check this link for some options on this error: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#windows-server-core-version